# Circuit review acceptable?

Tags: discussion

Is it acceptable to post a question (with the community wiki option) along the lines of:

> Please review this circuit design for
>   doing blah and let me know how it can
>   be improved / is anything wrong with
>   it from a common design perspective:
>
> --Insert Diagram Here--

This type of question seems to be electronics equivalent of coderview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would think ***yes***, it is acceptable, but not very interesting, and may not get much effort put into responses. A question should be definitively answerable (and the CW option used sparingly, not just to mask bad questions). It would be better to ask multiple questions, each with a different goal though they may all use the same circuit diagram (or sections of the same one).

Maybe look at how this question panned out: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/8453/2118

It has a more specific goal than general circuit check, but was still quite general and received little attention.

Comment: the poster cannot choose community wiki anymore. It requires requesting a mod steps in and changes it. This allows a filter step to remove those bad questions you noted.

Comment: @RQDQ, on the note of circuit review, I have seen questions like this on PCB layout, but in general this type of question falls under "too localized: This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet." The issue is simple, the feedback that you receive is really not going to be valuable to the general audience of the internet as your situation is so minor.

Comment: You could argue that a schematic review is good for someone else to read and learn from, but this should really be a, what should be reviewed(which honestly is too broad). As just having random schematic reviews on the site will build up to a very large number with random quality and little value.

Comment: The better the design, the more worthy it is of design review and the value of feedback content from those with experience.  Poor designs would be too broad. Excellent designs can be reviewed by those with adequate experience. @Kortuk FYI but from what I see from this site, points and experience do not always correlate. It only indicates a matched BW , yes I like this simple clear answer to a simple problem and understand better. I.e. lower the  bandwidth or technical difficulty, the more points as Moderators fail to know how to raise the bar of the community. Which is why so many leave.