# Schematic and PCB Review

Tags: discussion

Apologies if this is the incorrect place, I read the forum rules and I do want to ask a specific question; however, I wanted to make sure this was the right place to ask it first...

My questions is about Schematic and PCB review, more precisely does this forum do that or have any recommendations of forums that participate in Schematic and PCB reviews?

I am a single electrical engineer at my company and work remotely; therefore, I am looking for an online place to do schematic and PCB reviews.

EDIT: Thanks to the person who moved this topic. I didn't have enough reputation to post in the meta forum - the place I assumed this topic most correctly belonged.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Circuit review acceptable?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/399/circuit-review-acceptable)

Comment: @JYelton Yes possibly in the first instance for this board. But not in the second instance in where are there ones out there being available?

Comment: I'll add an answer to give my thoughts.

Answer (score 12):

As in the [meta question I linked](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399/circuit-review-acceptable), EE.SE has discussed and allowed circuit and PCB design review questions. However, they need to be well-formulated and focused. In other words, you probably shouldn't post a schematic or PCB layout and say "What do you think of this?!"

If you browse through existing questions of this nature, you'll find some good examples. They focus on a specific aspect of the circuit or PCB, and ask things like:

- [How's my crystal oscillator layout?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/5597/2028)
- [Have a look at my PCB design and tell me how I can improve](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/6078/2028)
- [What is causing large oscillations in my DC/DC boost converter? Is this ground bounce or some other effect?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/22898/2028)
- [Stabilizing opamps - am I doing it right?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/32986/2028)

Some of these are better examples than others, but the idea is to point out something specific and ask about it.

So the answer to your first question:

> ... Does this forum do that?

Is "Yes, it does. (But please note it is ***not*** a forum.)"

The answer to your second question:

> [Does this forum] have any recommendations of forums that participate in Schematic and PCb reviews?

Is "No. Such questions would not be a good format for the site, because there is no *correct* answer, and lists of other sites would likely become out of date and difficult to maintain."

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't mind looking over schematics, (assuming there is some quid pro quo),  and maybe simple pcb questions.  If the pcb's are too complicated I just get lost in all the colors. :^)  I'm also almost alone at my company when it comes to circuit questions.  You can also try asking questions on the usernet forum sci.electronics.design.  Warning! SED is considerably looser than here, and you may find that your question is hijacked as the people there want to talk about something else.  (It's also full of political and other off topic "noise".)  I'll still post questions there.  One thing that I've found is that more than 1/2 the time the act of asking the question (in a way that the knowledgeable audience can understand and answer) is enough to let me see an answer.

That all said I'm new here also, and don't know how it could work.  Maybe very targeted questions at only a small piece of the entire circuit.